# IOUtils.toByteArray deprecated - what can we use instead?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a `spring boot` application and needed to use `toByteArray` method provided by `IOUtils`, but it is deprecated. Is it safe to use `string.getBytes()` instead in a `spring boot` application or is there another way to get bytes from a text content?

Comment: The API documentation is complete with methods that should be used instead of the deprecated ones. You can trust the API documentation.

Comment: just to add to @Torben comment, from documentation: use  `IOUtils.toByteArray(Reader, Charset)` instead. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/deprecated-list.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best is to use,

```
string.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

It is better to specify the encoding else default platform specific encoding may be used which may create unexpected results in case you have characters that can't be represented in default encoding like Arabic/Chinese/Hindi characters.

And UTF-8 is one of the best and compact encodings and covers over a million characters in other languages and emojis as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's **equivalent**, for 2 reasons:

- They claim it in the javadoc
- If you look at the implementation:

  ```
  /** @deprecated */
  @Deprecated
  public static byte[] toByteArray(String input) throws IOException {
      return input.getBytes();
  }
  ```

`getBytes()` is actually called.

But it's not **safe** because it makes the assumption that you want the bytes in the platform's default charset. You should always specify a charset.

Comment: It is "safe" as in "it won't crash on you". It is *not* safe however if you expect it to behave consistently whatever the underlying OS / JVM / envrionment variables". **Any** `String`/`char` to `byte` conversion should specify an encoding if you want predictability and consistency.

Comment: @GPI Correct. Changed the wording to "equivalent".